# Apollo GraphQl pagination - limit and skip

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I want to implement simple pagination with **skip** and **limit** parameters

In documentation ( https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/ ) I see:

> We could do something like friends(first:2 after:$friendId), to ask
>   for the next two after the last friend we fetched.

But if I pass *first* parameter in my query I get error:

> "message": "Unknown argument \"first\" on field \"documents\" of type
>   \"Query\".",

My query typeDef:

```
  extend type Query {
   documents(search: String, paragraphSize: Int, filters: DocumentFilters, sort: DocumentSort): [Document]
```

Question: should I add parameters **first** in my documents endpoint and handle all limits/skips/etc by myself on server side or I missed something and GraphQL handles by itself all limits etc?

Answer (score 0):

From your typeDef there is no parameter stating first or skip. it is not a parameter that exists already, it has to be defined

So something like this

`documents(search: String, paragraphSize: Int, filters: DocumentFilters, sort: DocumentSort, skip: Int, limit: Int): [Document]`

You could make another input to hold all these values if you wish